# Use angular on meteor : Good or Bad?

Tags: jquery, angular, meteor

I want to develop a WebApp with Meteor framework but it's new for me.
Therefore, i don't know which are the good practice on this framework.

Some tutorial use classic jquery, but it is good nowaday ?

Maybe it's better to add an angular module on meteor if this exists ?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: despite the question being opinion based, you shouldnt really use jquery nowadays as its outdated, so is angularjs so angular4+ would be where to start

Comment: As @mast3rd3mon said, SO is not really a platform for opinions.

Answer (score 1):

Meteor supports both Angular and React on front-end very well! Why don't you have a look at their [tutorials](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials) available for Angular, React and Blaze, first? They will give you a quite satisfactory understanding in very short-time.

Answer (score -1):

Meteor is different from most other front-end frameworks although there is some overlap. It is more like a platform which has components on both front-end and server side.

It is best suited for applications which need real-time connection between the server and the clients or for quick prototyping.

Angular and Meteor in one app is not a good combination. Look for other backend frameworks like loopback or feathersjs if you want to use Angular.